# Calling an async method using a Task.Run seems wrong?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I recently came across this code written by a contractor we had working for us. It's either devilishly clever or silly (I think the latter but I wanted a second opinion). I'm not massively up to speed on `async` `await`.

Basically it worked like this:

```
public bool Send(TemplatedMessageDto message)
{
    return Task.Run(() => SendAsync(message))
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
}

public async Task<bool> SendAsync(TemplatedMessageDto message)
{
    //code doing stuff
    var results = await _externalresource.DothingsExternally();
    //code doing stuff
}
```

Now as I understand it that first `Task.Run()` is pointless and inefficient? and should really be:

```
public bool Send(TemplatedMessageDto message)
{
    return SendAsync(message))
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
}

public async Task<bool> SendAsync(TemplatedMessageDto message)
{
    //code doing stuff
    var results = await _externalresource.DothingsExternally();
    //code doing stuff
}
```

I'm also not convinced this is really an async method because it will still wait, right? I think it's only advantage (even re-written) is to free up the main worker thread.

Can someone confirm that this first Task shouldn't be there?

Comment: Why the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` call instead of `.Result`? And why *wait* at all instead of writing `public async Task<bool> Send ... await Task.Run();` ?

Comment: If the "other stuff" is heavy enough `Task.Run` isn't inefficient - `async` doesn't *make* anything run asynchronously. Everything up to `await` will run on the calling thread. If you need it to run concurrently, you should use `Task.Run`, or better yet, extract it to its own method that will be called with Task.Run

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well, yes, this did cross my mind. I don't think he really understood what he was doing.

Comment: Do you actually _need_ the synchronous version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm also not convinced this is really an async method because it will still wait, right?

It isn't, as Yuval explained. You shouldn't use sync over async.

> Now as I understand it that first `Task.Run()` is pointless and inefficient?

Not really, there is value in using `Task.Run` in such a way.

Since you're blocking on an async method (which you shouldn't do) there is a chance you'll deadlock. That happens in UI apps and asp.net where you have a `SynchronizationContext`.

Using `Task.Run` clears that `SynchronizationContext` since it offloads the work to a `ThreadPool` thread and removes the risk for a deadlock.

**So, blocking is bad, but if you end up doing it using `Task.Run` is safer.**

Comment: Could you clarify the *blocking on an async method (which you shouldn't do)* bit. I'm a bit confused now. The `_externalresource` is a third party library that return `Task<List<value>>` and this method (my `Send()` method) just needs to confirm that that list contains values. I was going to just change this to a syncohonous method and use the `.Result`, but I think your saying that's a bad idea?

Comment: @Liam Blocking on asynchronous methods is usually a bad idea. It hurts performance and can lead to deadlocks. It's much preferable to make your entire flow async.

Comment: @Liam If you must have a synchronous option it's better if you use synchronous calls all the way (i.e. `var results = _externalresource.DothingsExternally()`) but if this doesn't exist then sync over async is inevitable.

Comment: Maybe it's the library that's silly then. I think I may post a follow on question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have [posted a follow on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609925/async-library-calls-relying-on-each-other-and-how-to-handle) if your interested?

Answer (score 7):

> I'm also not convinced this is really an async method because it will still wait, right?

What your contractor did is use the [sync over async anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). He probably did so to save himself from creating an additional method which does its work synchronously. He is unnecessarly invoking `Task.Run` and immediately blocking on it using `GetResult`.

Using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will propogate the inner exception, if such happens, instead of the wrapped `AggregateException`.

> I think it's only advantage (even re-written) is to free up the main worker thread.

Both your version and his will block the main thread while executing, while his will also do so by using a threadpool thread. As Bar mentioned, this can help avoid deadlocks with issues regarding to synchronization context marshaling. I would recommend creating a synchronous equivalent if needed.