# async library calls relying on each other and how to handle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

this is a follow on from a previous question I posted [Calling an async method using a Task.Run seems wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606485/calling-an-async-method-using-a-task-run-seems-wrong)

I thought the code written by the contractor was wrong but following on from the answers provided I'm now wondering if it's the libraries fault. This library exposes two methods that I need to use. One returns a "template" and one consumes part of this template (it does in my implementation anyway). But both are `async` methods returning `Tasks`.

To explain my library has methods:

```
public Task<TemplateInfo> TemplateInfo(TemplateInfoRequest request);
public Task<List<EmailResult>> SendMessageTemplate(SendMessageTemplateRequest request);
```

I need to call these thus:

```
public bool SendMessage()
{
  var template = TemplateInfo(...);
  var message = //use template to create message
  var sendResponse = SendMessageTemplate(message);

   return sendResponse.Count > 0;
}
```

So the second call relies on the first. This is where the async doesn't make sense to me. <strike>I can't and don't want to run these in parallel. I want to run them in sequence.</strike> I want **my** method to by synchonous.

An [answer in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607091/542251) also states:

> Since you're blocking on an async method (**which you shouldn't do**)
>   there is a chance you'll deadlock.

So how do I access these `async` methods in such a way that they are processed in turn and return a synconhonous result but do not cause deadlocks?

Comment: Liam you are very very very confused. Async does not mean concurrent.

Comment: @Aron: Asynchrony is one form of concurrency. However, asynchrony is not the same as *parallelism*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async doesn't (necessarily) means parallel.

You can call both async method **sequentially** without them running in parallel. Simply call the first and **await** the returned task and then do the same with the second.

```
var template = await TemplateInfo(...);
var message = //use template to create message
var sendResponse = await SendMessageTemplate(message);
```

This is still useful compared to synchronous code because while the asynchronous operation is "running" there's no thread needed and so your threads can go work on other parts of your application.

If you would call both and only then await the returned tasks you will (maybe) run in parallel:

```
var templateTask = TemplateInfo(...);
var sendResponseTask = SendMessageTemplate(message);
await templateTask;
await sendResponseTask;
```

Comment: I suggest you add a bit about non-blocking async I/O to clear up the advantages out sequential async.

Comment: But to add an `await`, I then have to mark my method as `async` and return a `Task`, I just want a single value, synchronously. I was going to just use `.Result` but then I'm blocking on an async aren't I? Which I thought I shouldn't do. I've added detail in the question.

Comment: I suppose I'm confused, at some point I need to stop calling async methods and for it to be synchonous. Or else how do I let the user know what's happened. So how do I gracefully get out of this without "blocking"

Comment: @Liam The best option is async all the way up. This requires changing the method calls until you reach the top (which can be an event handler, `Main` and so forth). If you can't do that for some reason then the next option is to not use async at all and have synchronous code all the way down. If that's not an option (because you use a library that has async only API) then you don't have any option other than blocking on async code and then try to make sure it's done safely.