# Many awaits for Async method, or a single await for a wrapping Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Suppose we have to write down on database a list of 1000 elements, through an async flow. Is it better to await 1000 times an asynchronous insert statement, or to wrap all the 1000 inserts in one single synchronous method encapsulated into a `Task.Run` statement, awaiting one single time?

For example, `SqlCommand` has every method coupled with his `async` version. In this case, we have an insert statement, so we can call `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Often, on async/await guidelines, we read that if you have an asynchronous version available for some method, you should use it. So suppose we write:

```
async Task Save(IEnumerable<Savable> savables)
{
    foreach(var savable in savables)
    {
        //create SqlCommand somehow
        var sqlCmd = CreateSqlCommand(savable);

        //use asynchronous version
        await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

This code is very clear. However, every time it goes out from the await part, it also returns on the UI thread, and then back in a background thread in the next await encountered, and so on (doesn't it?). This implies that the user can see some lag, since the UI Thread is continously interrupted by the continuation of the `await` to execute the next `foreach` cycle, and in that fraction of time the UI freezes a bit.

I want to know if I better write code like this:

```
async Task Save(IEnumerable<Savable> savables)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach(var savable in savables)
        {
            //create SqlCommand somehow
            var sqlCmd = CreateSqlCommand(savable);

            //use synchronous version
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    });
}
```

In this way, the whole `foreach` is executed on the secondary thread, without a continuous switch between the UI thread and the secondary one.
This implies that the UI thread is free to update the View for the entire duration of the `foreach` (for example a spinner or a progress bar), that is, no lag is perceived by the user.

Am I right? or am I missing something about "async all the way down"?

I'm not looking for simple opinion-based answers, I'm looking for an explanation of async/await guidelines in case like that and for the best way to resolve it.

**EDIT:**

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606485/calling-an-async-method-using-a-task-run-seems-wrong) but it is not the same. THAT question is about the choice of a SINGLE `await` on an async method versus a single `Task.Run` await. THIS question is about the consequences of calling 1000 `await` and the resources' overhead due to the continuous switching among threads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an async method using a Task.Run seems wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606485/calling-an-async-method-using-a-task-run-seems-wrong)

Comment: What you are missing is that Threads are extremely expensive, so you actually want to avoid creating them if you can.

Comment: the `Task.Run` method is an the *sync over async anti pattern*. Don't do it

Comment: `async all the way down` is generally referring to high-level application architecture.  Your method returns a `Task` to consumers (thumbs up), but what goes on inside the method is implementation details.

Comment: You can use `ConfigureAwait` to tell it not to continue on the original thread, but in your case you'd only want to do that if nothing after the `await` requires the UI thread (like updating a UI control).

Comment: But you already have a thread, why do you want another?

Comment: In the first (correct) way, most likely no threads are created or destroyed anyway, just couple of threads are getting in and out the thread pool. Also you can add ConfigureAwait(false) to your ExecuteNonQueryAsync to prevent returning back to UI thread.

Comment: Alternatively you could capture the result from `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` and push it to an array of `Task` and then use `await Task.WhenAll(taskArray)`

Comment: @Evk You are wrong. It is the second example where the threadpool is used. The first one is SINGLE THREADED.

Comment: @Aron but if you add ConfigureAwait(false), it will use thread pool to run continuations, itsn't it?

Comment: @Evk yes. But in the original, everything runs only on the UI thread.

Comment: @Liam the question you indicate as a duplicate, is not actually the same of this. This question is not about deadlocks, or a redundant use of `Task.Run` / `await` statements. It is only about the choice between `Task.Run` and 1000 await, which one is better and why.

Comment: OP you may want to read this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus: `I'm looking for an explanation of async/await guidelines` The guideline is "no more than 100 continuations per second on the UI thread" (doc'd [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html)). You can avoid UI continuations via `ContinueWith`.

Comment: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming By Stephen Cleary | March 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your analysis is largely correct.  You seem to overestimate the burden that this would place on the UI thread; the actual work that it would be asked to do is fairly small, so odds are that it would be able to keep up fine, but it's possible that you'd be doing enough that it couldn't, so you're right to be interested in not performing the continuations on the UI thread.

What you're missing of course is the preferred way of avoiding all of the call backs to the UI thread.  When you `await` an operation, if you don't actually need the rest of the method to return back to the original context you can simply add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the end of the task that you're awaiting.  This will prevent the continuation from running in the current context (which is the UI thread) and instead let the continuation run in a thread pool thread.

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` allows you to avoid the UI being responsible for non-UI work unnecessarily while also preventing you from needing to schedule thread pool threads to do more work than they need to do.

Of course, if the work that you end up doing after your continuation is actually going to do UI work, then that method shouldn't be using `ConfigureAwait(false);`, because it actually *wants* to schedule the continuation on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok, I have the choice to use `ConfigureAwait`, and from the point of view of the result, now I have 2 quite identical options. Now, why should I use `ConfigureAwait` instead of the `Task.Run`? Is it only a matter of readability?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus It means that the continuations, after the async operation runs, will run on the thread pool, rather than getting the thread pool to *start* the asynchronous actions (as well as handle all of the continuations).  Using `ConfigureAwait` also allows you to have all of the methods that *don't* need to run on the UI thread use the thread pool while allowing anything that needs to use the UI to simply not add `ConfigureAwait(false)` and be able to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what the UI is expecting. If the UI depends on the operation being complete in order to retain a valid state then you have no choice but to wait for the async task or use a call on the main UI thread as you would normally.

Threading is great for tasks that take a long time but are NOT required by the calling thread immediately or the calling thread is dependant on the result of the operation.

Tasks are no there to speed things up, they are there for efficiency. So you could keep the task thread and raise an event with an 'operation completed' leaving the UI to operate normally while this operation is happening, but like I said if the UI thread depends on the result, you have no choice but to wait.

If you go via the event route, you can update your UI asynchronously with the results as they come in

Answer (score -2):

There is one important difference between the two solutions. The first one is single-threaded (unless you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as suggested by @Servy), while the second one is multi-threaded.

Multi-threadedness always introduces extra complexity to your program. You should start by asking yourself if you're willing to trade that for the benefits you might gain.

Comment: actually you don't know if the library you are using has a `Task.Run` inside or not. You can have the situation described in the "there is no thread" comment (see under the question), or you can have a library that exposes an `async` method that inside has a `Task.Run`. In the latter case, the flow IS multi-threaded, even if from the outside you use only an `await`.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Agreed, but I think that misses the point. ANY library you call can obviously have hidden multi-threaded code inside it. I'm specifically talking about introducing multi-threading with the code you choose to write.