# In the context of ASP.NET, why doesn't Task.Run(...).Result deadlock when calling an async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task, synchronizationcontext

I created a simple WebApi project with a single controller and a single method:

```
public static class DoIt
{
    public static async Task<string> GetStrAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var str = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            return str;
        }
    }
}

public class TaskRunResultController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
            DoIt.GetStrAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"))
        );
        var result = task.Result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have a good understanding of async/await and tasks; almost religiously following Stephen Cleary. Just the existence of `.Result` makes me anxious, and I expect this to deadlock. I understand that the `Task.Run(...)` is wasteful, causing a thread to be occupied while waiting for the async `DoIt()` to finish.

The problem is *this is not deadlocking*, and it's giving me heart palpitations.

I see some answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607091/1801382, and I've also observed that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null when the lambda is executing. However, there are similar questions to mine asking why the above code *does* deadlock, and I've seen deadlocks occur in cases where `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used (not capturing the context) in conjunction with `.Result`.

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Result` by itself isn't going to cause a deadlock. A deadlock is when two parts of the code are both waiting for each other. A `Result` is just one wait, so it can be part of a deadlock, but it doesn't necessarily *always* cause a deadlock.

In the [standard example](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), the `Result` waits for the task to complete *while holding onto the context*, but the task can't complete because it's *waiting for the context to be free*. So there's a deadlock - they're waiting for each other.

[ASP.NET Core does not have a context at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html), so `Result` won't deadlock there. (It's still not a good idea for other reasons, but it won't *deadlock*).

> The problem is this is not deadlocking, and it's giving me heart palpitations.

This is because the `Task.Run` task does not require the context to complete. So calling `Task.Run(...).Result` is safe. The `Result` is waiting for the task to complete, and it is holding onto the context (preventing any other parts of the request from executing in that context), but that's OK because the `Task.Run` task doesn't need the context at all.

`Task.Run` is still not a good idea in general on ASP.NET (for other reasons), but this is a perfectly valid technique that is useful from time to time. It won't ever deadlock, because the `Task.Run` task doesn't need the context.

> However, there are similar questions to mine asking why the above code does deadlock,

Similar but not exact. Take a careful look at each code statement in those questions and ask yourself what context it runs on.

> and I've seen deadlocks occur in cases where ConfigureAwait(false) is used (not capturing the context) in conjunction with .Result.

The `Result`/context deadlock is a very common one - probably the most common one. But it's not the only deadlock scenario out there.

[Here's an example](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) of a much more difficult deadlock that can show up if you block *within* `async` code (*without* a context). This kind of scenario is much more rare, though.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I suspected the answer was essentially "this is because the Task.Run task does not require the context to complete," but was hesitant to call this "safe." I understand the other repercussions. Thanks for the blocking example; as it's now 2017, is the rarer scenario still valid? You also state this will not occur in GUI or ASP.NET code - in which scenario _does_ it deadlock?

Comment: Yes. `await` still uses `ExecuteSynchronously`, so the more rare scenario is still valid. In this case it's a deadlock where two thread pool threads are waiting for each other.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you as short answer the other way around: how to produce a deadlock:

Lets start in a `Click` handler that is executing synchronous and offloading some async call to a separate Task, then waiting for the result

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => DeadlockProducer(sender as MenuItem));
    var result = t.Result;
}

private async Task<int> DeadlockProducer(MenuItem sender)
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => sender.Header = "Life sucks");
    return 0;
}
```

The async method is doing another bad thing: it tries to bring some UI change synchronously, but the UI thread is still waiting for the task result...

So basically, `Task.Run` is half way out and will work for a lot of well formed async code, but there are ways to break it, so its not a reliable solution.

This sample code was written in context of WPF, but I guess ASP.Net could be abused to produce similar behavior.