# Why access Task.Result in the synchronous mode doesn't cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

As we all know to access the Result property of Task in the UI thread and synchronous mode will deadlock.

As theoretical follow code will deadlock but not. Can you please explain why?

```
// My "library" method.
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}

//MVC action
public ActionResult Index()
{
      var result = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await GetJsonAsync(...)).Result; // deadlock is expectation but not :(

    ...
}
```

I thought that `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await GetJsonAsync(...)).Result` is simialar to `GetJsonAsync(...).Result` in some way, but not.

`GetJsonAsync(...)).Result` will deadlock
but `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await GetJsonAsync(...)).Result` is not.

Comment: What's the runtime? ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Task.Run() in synchronous method to avoid deadlock waiting on async method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305968/use-task-run-in-synchronous-method-to-avoid-deadlock-waiting-on-async-method)

Comment: @PauloMorgado it must not be .Net core if `.Result` caused a deadlock.

Comment: There is no deadlock in case of asp.net core because of empty synchronization context. Also Task.Run schedules your method to threadpool so no sync. context is captured. That's why GetJsonAsync().Result will deadlock: sync.context is captured. Read it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814404/in-the-context-of-asp-net-why-doesnt-task-run-result-deadlock-when-callin

Comment: @GSerg you're right, probably they have some similar content

Comment: @mtkachenko yeah, thanks I got it. I don't know that Task.Run schedules the method to threadpool. That makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Result` doesn't cause a deadlock *by itself*. It causes a deadlock when called from a single-threaded context **if** there is an `await` for that task that also needs that context.

[More details](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html):

- `await` by default captures a context and resumes on that context. (You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to override this default behavior and resume on a thread pool thread instead.)
- `Result` blocks the current thread until that `Task` is complete. (You can use `await` to consume a task asynchronously to avoid blocking a thread.)
- Some contexts are single-threaded contexts; i.e., they only allow one thread in at a time. E.g., ASP.NET Classic has a single-threaded request context. (You can use `Task.Run` to run code on a thread pool thread, with a thread pool context, which is not a single-threaded context.)

So, to get a deadlock, you need to have an `await` that captures a single-threaded context, and then block a thread inside that context (e.g., calling `Result` on that task). The `await` needs the context to complete the `Task`, but the context only allows one thread at a time, and the `Result` is keeping a thread blocked in that context until the `Task` completes.

In your example, you're calling `GetJsonAsync` inside a `Task.Run`, which runs it on the thread pool. So the `await` in `GetJsonAsync` (and the `await` in the delegate passed to `Task.Run`) capture the thread pool context, not the ASP.NET request thread context. Then your code calls `Result`, which *does* block the ASP.NET request thread (and its context), but since the `await` doesn't need that context, there's no deadlock.