# Web Forms aspx - PostAsync Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms

1. I have a Web Forms application calling a Web API post action but it is not working.
2. Calling the Post action from Swagger and Postman is working. So am thinking the issue is not in the Web API.
3. Have tried using the PostAsJsonAsync function but the outcome is the same.
4. The execution hangs at the line "HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/create", RawText);"
5. Kindly assist

**Web Forms Method**

```
        public async Task<CSSetup> CSCreateSetup(CSAudit TempAudit)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var APIPath = Session["APIPath"].ToString();
                CSSetup TempSetup = new CSSetup();

                //Content
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempAudit);
                var RawText = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                //HttpClient
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIPath);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/create", RawText);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    TempSetup = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CSSetup>();
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["Message"] = "Error creating setup";
                }

                return await Task.FromResult(TempSetup);
            }
        }
```

**Post Action**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateSetup(CSAudit TempAudit)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await setupManager.CSCreateSetup(TempAudit));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,  "Error creating setup object");
            }
        }
```

**Calling CreateSetup**

```
        protected async void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var TempAudit = new CSAudit("ADMIN", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            CSSetup TempSetup = (CSCreateSetup(TempAudit)).Result;
        }
```

**What I have tried**

1. Created the Web API Post action and the Web Form method to consume the Post action
2. I was expecting the Web Forms data to Post the data supplied and return the expected data

Comment: How are you calling `CSCreateSetup` from within WebForms? You can only use `async` methods in WebForms in the special async call-sites, and you need `async="true"` in your `<%@ Page`  _and_ you need to tweak stuff in your `web.config`.

Comment: @Dai I have added async=true in the <%@Page section

Comment: @Dai I have edited the question to show how am calling CreateSetup

Comment: What you've posted won't work: you can't use `async` methods from within WebForms Server-Side events methods (like your `BtnSave_Click`). You need to read through this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 - you can only call `async` methods from within `RegisterAsyncTask`.

Comment: @Dai, I have a similar asynchronous Get function being called on PageLoad and it is working

Comment: If it works, it's only because of a miracle - it certainly isn't guaranteed to work in actual use in production.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the call to include Result and removed the await. Have also removed the async key word from the CreateSetup method.

**Old Code**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/create", RawText);
```

**New Code**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/create", RawText).Result;
```

Comment: ....that's not going to work either. It will deadlock at some point and leave request threads hanging. Also, please don't thank me because I would never recommend anyone ever do this.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks

Comment: and this is also relevant to what you're doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828280/why-access-task-result-in-the-synchronous-mode-doesnt-cause-a-deadlock where StephenCleary explains why it "works" in ASP.NET, and also why its still a bad idea.

Comment: @Dai, So removing async from the method and removing await is still a bad idea?

Comment: Instead of trying to force `HttpClient` to work in a way it's not intended to - I'll suggest you use the non-async `HttpWebRequest` class instead.

Comment: Okay, let me check it out

Answer (score 0):

Have changed the CreateSetup Method to below. Hope it helps someone else

```
    public CSSetup CSCreateSetup(CSAudit TempAudit)
    {
        //Global
        var APIPath = Session["APIPath"].ToString();
        var uri = APIPath + "/api/setup/create";
        CSSetup TempSetup = new CSSetup();

        //Content 
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempAudit);

        // Create a request object
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = json.Length;

        // Write the JSON data to the request stream
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        // Get the response from the server
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                TempSetup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CSSetup>(responseString);
            }
        }

        return TempSetup;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**